# Heroku simple app python - virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv

```
 MacBook-Anutka:helloflask root# virtualenv venv --distribute
 -sh: virtualenv: command not found
```

Error - command not found

Comment: And... Is virtualenv installed? What happens when you type `which virtualenv`

Comment: also, does this have any specific connection to heroku?

Answer (score 0):

Use this command:

`pip install virtualenv`......